# Flutter - How to use multiple package builders?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use multiple package builder, `flutter_screenutil` and `flutter_easyloading`.

`ScreenUtilInit` gives this error:

```
AssertionError ('package:flutter_easyloading/src/widgets/loading.dart': Failed assertion: line 34 pos 16: 'child != null': is not true.)
```

My code is:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ScreenUtilInit(
    designSize: const Size(360, 640),
    // designSize: const Size(414, 736),
    builder: (context, child) {
      child = EasyLoading.init()(context,child);
      child = GetMaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: myApp,
        // You can use the library anywhere in the app even in theme
        // theme: ThemeData(
        //   primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        //   textTheme: Typography.englishLike2018.apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.sp),
        // ),
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          // textTheme: GoogleFonts.nunitoTextTheme(
          //   Theme.of(context).textTheme,
          // ),
          textTheme: Typography.englishLike2018.apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.sp),
        )
      );
      return child;
    },
  );
}
```